# Getting civicrm in Israel and in Hebrew and English

Tags: installation, evaluating-civicrm, i18n

Is this program available in Israel, also with Hebrew and English?  I would want to have it customized to our needs. 
Thanks,
Debbie Perla
Hannaton Educational Center

Comment: You might try collaborating with other organizations to share the cost.

Answer (score 4):

The program is Open Source, so it is available everywhere.

When you download CiviCRM at https://civicrm.org/download/list you can also download the Localization files.

The Hebrew language is available in there, although not all texts are translated yet.

But I am pretty sure you can adjust it to your needs and make sure you can at least translate anything that is shown to your visitors.

On one of my CiviCRM's I have set the language to Hebrew, so you can have an insight how much is generally translated. 
[image: Hebrew CiviCRM]

If you choose CiviCRM for your organization and you would do some extra translation for your site we'd love to help you give it back to the community. We would all benefit from it.

(More info: https://www.transifex.com/civicrm/civicrm/)

Comment: Also go to demo.civicrm.org and change the demo site language to Hebrew at Administer -> Administration Console -> Localization

Answer (score 2):

While CiviCRM is available in Israel, you would probably need to help out with the translation effort to Hebrew. Currently only 12% of the strings are translated.

https://www.transifex.com/civicrm/civicrm/language/he/

This is very easy, you just need to create a transifex account. More details on translation for CiviCRM can be found here :
https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Resources+for+Translators

Answer (score 0):

CiviCRM is available in Israel as well as any other country. I don't know of a Hebrew version available for download. You can definitely have it translated as part of your customization.